# Sharing PS4 games between 2 consoles

Tags: ps4, psn, playstation-plus

I have a (probably reposted) question about PS4.
I'm thinking of buying it and one of the main reasons is that I will be able to share the games with another person, meaning that we can go 50/50 on the price.

I've read that you can legally share your games with another *console* just by putting your account as primary on the fellow console. But what happens when the PS4 has more than one user?

Let me make an example.

I will have the PS4 and I have a brother. We are going to have two users, because I don't want him to play on my savefiles. So, I will buy my games on my PSN account, and trade them with my friend's account. So in my user, I'm going to have as primary my friend's account, secondary mine, and my friend will do the opposite.

Question: is there a chance that my brother in his account will be able to play the games that my friend shared to me? Will it overwrite any save? Will he need to log in as my friend's primary account?

So that's it, sorry for my English, I'm Argentinian, and I hope I made myself clear.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this site](http://gadgets.ndtv.com/games/features/how-to-share-ps4-games-using-psn-718099), you are able to do what you described for you and your friend to share games. However, in order to play your own games, you will be required to have an active connection to the internet **at all times**, which is less than ideal.

However, because your own PS4 will not be registered as *your* primary PS4, no one besides you can access your games on your PS4. However, everyone who has access to your console will be able to play your *friend's* games, since that would be the account with your PS4 listed as its primary. Likewise, anyone that plays on your friend's PS4 could access games that you have purchased on your account.

Savefiles are kept on a per-account basis, so any games that your brother plays on his account will not affect you or your friend's savefiles in any way.

Answer (score 0):

In order to share games you need to have access to the two accounts you want to access them on. First off you and your friend will need to log in to the other's account and set the primary ps4, and that is that. When you want to download a game from the other's account you need to log in as their user to download it. However here is the catch with this game sharing process, you will not be able to play your own games when you do not have internet. Anything purchased on your account will only work on your friend's PS4 when it is offline. Also your brother will be able to access the games of yours and your friends if they are installed, but the same rule applies if he wants to play games from your account. He will not have access to your save files as those are user specific.