# PS Plus subscription for 2 consoles?

Tags: ps4

This may or may not have been answered but i couldn't find the right response to my question.

Right now, my brother has his own PS4 console with his account (primary) which he bought the PS Plus subscription on so he can play online/multiplayer games. Also on this console is my account (sub account) which has been shared under the primary account so i can play online/multiplayer on this account also.

My query is, if i buy my own PS4 console and log into my account (the sub account on my brother's PS4), will i be able to still use PS Plus and play online/multiplayer?

Answer (score 8):

No, Playstation Plus benefits are only granted from a primary account to a sub account **locally**. While you'd have online access on your brother's PS4, you'd need to purchase your own Playstation Plus subscription in order to have the same access on your own console.

Comment: what if my brother logs in on my ps4, set it as the primary ps4, then i log into my account still as the sub account so the first situation is replicated but on my ps4. Then he logs into his account on his ps4 still as the primary account?

Comment: @lohboys an account can only have one primary console. You can't have multiple primary consoles.

Comment: so there is no way both accounts could play online/multiplayer together on 2 ps4's without both buying PS Plus?

Comment: @lohboys that is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Reading between the lines in both the main post and some of your comments, it sounds as if you may be asking if there's a way for you to continue to use his account's PS Plus access to let you play multiplayer online games. (Whether this is or isn't the case, you should edit your question to make the situation clear.)

One solution, [as described in this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/288775/124847), is to have him set *your* console as his primary console (after deactivating his). You will then be able to use your account on your console with his PS Plus access, and he will also have PS Plus access on his console, but only for his account. (And he must also always have Internet connectivity available.) You would no longer be able to log in to his console and use his PS Plus access.